# Passing variable number of columns to Pyspark .Agg()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In PySpark I need to build a list of columns on runtime and then aggregate on them.

This is an example that works:

```py
T.agg(col1,col2)
```

But I need to pass a list of columns type List of Column (not string)

Doesn't work:

```py
cols=[col1,col2]   
T.agg(cols)     #Passes param as tupple1(List)
```

Doesn't work:

```py
cols=[col1,col2]    
T.agg(tupple(cols))      #Passes param as tupple1(tupple2)
```

Both cases fail on PySpark code:
`assert all(isinstance(c, Column) for c in exprs), "all exprs should be Column"`

Problem is that Python passes the list as tupple1 I need to pass a list of columns. What's the solution?

Comment: What type of aggregation do you want to do?

Comment: Specifically first found element my code is like this:
T = T.agg(first(OUTPUTS[0]).alias(OUTPUTS[0]),first(OUTPUTS[1]).alias(OUTPUTS[1])).alias("T")

I need to have a list as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need to unpack the list into individual parameter. You can do this using the `*` operator.

```py
T.agg(*cols)
```

The `*` unpacks the elements in the list. Here is another toy example, which independent of PySpark.

```py
def test(a, b, c, d):
    print(a, b, c, d)

data = [3, 4, 5, 6]
test(*data)

# Output:
# 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, if you want to do a 'first' aggregation, you can do:

```
col_list = ['col1', 'col2']
exprs = [first(i).alias("first_"+i) for i in col_list]

df.groupBy("some_col").agg(*exprs).show()
```